# Can we access paragraph field in views-view-unformatted.twig?

Tags: views, 8, theming

Is there a way to access the fields in paragraph in views-view-unformatted.twig.
I want to perform checking on field of paragraph before print the row
something like this

```
{% for row in rows %}
  {%
    set row_classes = [
      default_row_class ? 'views-row',
    ]
  %}
  {% if paragraph_field is not null %}
     <div {{ row.attributes.addClass(row_classes) }}>
        {{ row.content }}
     </div>
  {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you can get the value of field from paragraph field inside `views-view-unformatted.twig` all you can get is the `target_id` of referenced paragraph using `view.result[key]._entity`:

I suggest to use [`template_preprocess_views_view_unformatted`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21views%21views.theme.inc/function/template_preprocess_views_view_unformatted/8.2.x) like the following:

```
function YOURTHEME_preprocess_views_view_unformatted(&$variables) {
  $view = $variables['view'];
  $rows = $variables['rows'];
  if ($view->id() === 'YOUR_VIEW_ID') {
    $paragraph_storage = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('paragraph');
    foreach ($rows as $id => $row) {
      /** @var \Drupal\node\Entity\Node $node */
      $node = $view->result[$id]->_entity;
      // Get paragraph field.
      // Change field_paragraph by your filed ref to paragraph.
      if ($node->hasField('field_paragraph')) {
        $paragraph_ref_id = $node->field_paragraph->getValue()[0]['target_id'] ?? NULL;
        if ($paragraph_ref_id) {
          /** @var \Drupal\paragraphs\Entity\Paragraph $paragraph_entity */
          $paragraph_entity = $paragraph_storage->load($paragraph_ref_id);
          // Get the value of your field.
          // Change field_paragraph_text by your field.
          // And set another variable to use in twig.
          $variables['rows'][$id]['should_display_row'] = ($paragraph_entity->field_paragraph_text->value !== NULL) ? TRUE : FALSE;
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Now in your `views-view-unformatted.twig` you can check on `row.should_display_row` like the following:

```
{% for row in rows %}
  {%
    set row_classes = [
      default_row_class ? 'views-row',
    ]
  %}
  {% if row.should_display_row %}
    <div{{ row.attributes.addClass(row_classes) }}>
      {{- row.content -}}
    </div>
  {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Great answer. But I did use hook_views_query_alter to add condition for paragraph field.

Comment: How did you do that, I'm interested in the reverse, accessing view fields inside a paragraphs template